# MYSQL :INSERT INTO a new column based on duplicate entries in another column

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and i have a mysql table like this :

```
+-------+-------+
| block | CLASS |
+-------+-------+
| 1     | 3112  |
| 2     | 3131  |
| 3     | 3131  |
| 4     | 3131  |
| 5     | 3131  |
| 6     | 3131  |
| 7     | 2131  |
| 8     | 1131  |
| 9     | 1131  |
| 10    | 1131  |
+-------+-------+
```

I wish to add a new column 'LABEL' after the CLASS column. The LABEL class should have values 1,2,3 etc but only insert the same value for duplicate entries in the CLASS label. So the new LABEL column should look like this .

```
+-------+-------+----------+
| block | CLASS | LABEL    |
+-------+-------+----------+
| 1     | 3112  | 1        |
| 2     | 3131  | 2        |
| 3     | 3131  | 2        |
| 4     | 3131  | 2        |
| 5     | 3131  | 2        |
| 6     | 3131  | 2        |
| 7     | 2131  | 3        |
| 8     | 1131  | 4        |
| 9     | 1131  | 4        |
| 10    | 1131  | 4        |
+-------+-------+----------+
```

i don't have any keys defined for any of the columns as of yet. What is the best tool in mysql to achieve this and which statements will i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rank query

```
UPDATE t
JOIN (
SELECT `block`,
@r:=CASE WHEN @g = `CLASS` THEN @r ELSE @r + 1 END AS rownum,
@g:= `CLASS`
FROM t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:=NULL,@r:=0) t2
ORDER BY `block`,`CLASS`
  ) t1 
  ON (t.`block` = t1.`block`)
  SET t.`LABEL` = t1.rownum
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58244/1)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid : Suppose the duplicates are not in order as shown above then the query assigns them a wrong label. Lets say block 8, 9 and 10 belong to class 3112 then the label should be 1. However the current query assigns them a different label. How to achieve this if duplicates are out of order?

Comment: @srai then replace order by clause with `ORDER BY CLASS` only [*see updated demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/032d2/1)